# Configurable product prices are not changing with the variant selection

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento2.3.5-p2, configurable-product-options, configurable-price

I have imported products from another Magento webshop, and both webshops are using Magento 2.3.5.

On the frontend, specifically on the configurable product detail page, the prices are not updating in (Default) 1 of 3 stores when we change the variant. However, the other two stores are functioning correctly.

This issue only occurs with the newly imported products, while existing configurable products display the correct price when the variant is changed in any store. Interestingly, even though the correct price is added to the cart, it is not being displayed on the page.

**Following Error is showing under console on the store where it is not working**
[image]

1. pub/static/version/frontend/Alothemes/spozy6/sv_SE/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable.min.js 19

configurable.min.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

```
 _clearSelect: function(element) {
        var i;
        for (i = element.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            element.remove(i);
        }
    },
```

2. test-products-new.html:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')

   ```
     var product_id_index = jQuery('[data-role=swatch- 

   options]').data('mageSwatchRenderer').options.jsonConfig.index;
        var found_ids = [];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the presence of a block within the customized version of the theme's catalog_product_view.xml file. To resolve this, I reset the file to its default theme version. Subsequently, I created a new file in the child theme and identified the specific reference block that was causing the issue. By disabling this block, the prices are now updating correctly.